# convert an integer into a hex value which I can store in a byte array as hex value only in java

Tags: integer, hex

I want to convert an integer into a hex value which I can store in a byte array as hex value only.

For example, 
        int i = 18254;
The hex equivalent is 474E ( using Integer.toHexString ).
now I want to store this 474E in a byte array as 
        byte[0]=(byte)0x47
        byte[1]=(byte)0x4E
How can i do that?

Comment: Hex is a representation, not a value. Both values are the same, so they map on the same binary representation in memory. As such, storing the hex value makes no sense. Are you trying to do an int to byte conversion, ignoring leading zeros?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele : yes an int to a hexadecimal value which i can store in a byte array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just store the ints and an array and convert to hex using masks and shifting as required.

e.g. lowest byte in the int = `i & 0x00ff`, next highest = `(i & 0xff00) >> 8`.

You can use these same bit manipulations to store the bytes as you request.

`(i & 0xff00)` gets you the 2nd lowest byte in the int. `>> 8` shifts it right by 8 bits so it's now stored in the lower 8 bits.
`(i & 0xff0000)` gets you the 3rd byte (which you have to shift right by 16 bits) and so on.

so:

```
lowerByte = intVal & 0x000000ff;
secondLowest = (intVal & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
thirdLowest = (intVal & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
```

If you need all 4 bytes, you'll need to check how the sign bit is handled...

Comment: can u explain furthur?

Comment: here 474E is in string

Comment: Point is you don't need to convert it to a string at all. An int can already be represented as hex.

Comment: ya i got the decimal equivalent using above, like lowerByte=78 and secondLowest=71 which has values 4E and 47  in hex.now how can i get 4E AND 47 ?

Comment: decimal 78 is hex 4e. decimal 71 is hex 47. You just need to output as hex when required. You have not shown how you want to use this, so I can't really tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: I want to store this as byte b = (byte)0x4E. How can i do this? I am actually creating a Packet to be transmitted to UART

Comment: @Abinaya as noted in my other comment: hex is a *representation* of a value, not a value itself. You store `b = 01001110b`, which is the binary *representation* of "seventy-eight", simply because computer memory uses binary representation. It is irrelevant whether you want to interpret this value as it's binary representation (`01001110`), it's decimal representation (`78`), or it's hexa-decimal representation (`0x4E`). The consumer of your packet does not care and neither should you.